# Render sub-paragraph in parent template

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph that has a field of type paragraph reference to sub-paragraphs.

Within my template, I need to access these sub-paragraphs and render the entity element. I have a loop that loops through a list of `Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph` elements.

I need to render the paragraph markup.
Is there a function?

I tried `item|render` and `item.view()`, but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to render the sub paragraph - without any loop, just like every other field - with

`{{ content.field_name }}`

If you really need the loop for some special markup you can try something like

```
{% for key, item in content.field_name if key|first != '#' %}
  <div class="some_additional_markup">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Hudri. 
Your script does give me the exact list of results as my loop.
A list of Paragraphs. 
 {{ item }} is an object of type  Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph but this is not rendered. I need to turn them into markups. In D7 i used to use entity_view('paragraphs_item', $entities, 'full'); How to do this in D8? 

Is there a way to achieve this in Twig? Or should I create a Twig Function as the Twig context is not able to create markups of entities?

Comment: Are you using `{{ content.items }}` or `{{ paragraph.items }}`? The first should provide the render arrays, the latter should give you the objects. If that's not the case, it seems like an error to me. Regarding `entity_view`, I suggest to take a look at at the [Twig tweaks module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)

Comment: yeah u are right. Weird... tested it yesterday night and I could not render it. Thanks again

Comment: ok. but how to access the field of the paragraph as markups?

                {% set item_field_tax_1 = item|first.field_tax_1 %}
                {{ item_field_tax_1 }}

Gives me the error "Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList cannot be printed".

Comment: ok to anybody who will have this issue as well.

Please use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_render_this. It creates a twig extension that allows you to render Field Elements directly without having to use the predefined content element. Pretty much what I wanted to write myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a field value in child paragraph within the parent paragraph, you can use this (replace of course field_with_paragraph_childs and field_name_field with the actual fieldnames):

```
{% for key, item in paragraph.field_with_paragraph_childs if key|first != '#' %}
        <div class="some_additional_markup">
                {{ item.entity.field_name_field.value }}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```